# CSS Hover State in Drop Down Navigation

Tags: html, css, hover

I can't figure out why the hover state in my css does not work. I've been successful in hiding the sub navigation, but can't get it to reappear on rollover. I Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="writings.php">writings</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="devotionals.php">devotionals</a></li>
                <li><a href="published.php">published</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles.php">articles</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="fundraising.php">fundraising</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.php">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the css:

```
.nav {
position: relative;
margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: -50px;
}


.nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.nav > ul > li {
float: left;
font-size: 30px;
}

.nav ul::after {
content:''; 
display: block;
clear: both;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
float: left;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 90%;
display: none;
line-height: 5px;   
}

nav ul li a {
display: inline-block;
color: rgb(92,178,227);
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: should you either be using `nav ul` instead of `.nav ul` or adding the class "nav" to your `<nav>`?

Comment: Can you provide the full code? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also, you have invalid HTML.  You can't have a `<ul>` be a child of a `<ul>`.  The only valid child of a `<ul>` is a `<li>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the sub nav inside of the list item:

```
<li><a href="writings.php">writings</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="devotionals.php">devotionals</a></li>
            <li><a href="published.php">published</a></li>
            <li><a href="articles.php">articles</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Perfect! Total oversight. Thanks so much for catching that. I was pulling my hair out.